# how do i use windows accounts extension in an electron app

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, electron

We are using windows accounts extension to sign into chrome, however we have an app in our organisation that requires people ot sign in with their microsft accounts, and peopl are not able to login due to lack of the windows accounts extension,(This extension is used by microsoft to padss device id details that are needed to for conditional access on the user accounts)

We were able  to install the extension in electron but it doesnt do anything. we used this guide from elctron website [https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension#:~:text=To%20load%20an%20extension%20in,the%20extension%20in%20Google%20Chrome](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension#:%7E:text=To%20load%20an%20extension%20in,the%20extension%20in%20Google%20Chrome).

We were able  to install the extension in electron but it doesnt do anything. we used this guide from elctron website [https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension#:~:text=To%20load%20an%20extension%20in,the%20extension%20in%20Google%20Chrome](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension#:%7E:text=To%20load%20an%20extension%20in,the%20extension%20in%20Google%20Chrome).